# iPhone home screen icon for Super User is hard to see

Tags: feature-request, superuser, iphone, icons

I've recently started saving homescreen links to various Stack Exchange sites on my iPhone.
All of them look great, but the Super User icon, having dark gray on dark gray, looks like it's only half of the logo when viewed from a regular distance on the small phone screen.

Here is a screenshot of various logos, blown up to show the SU logo with more contrast.
(Just like cereal boxes!)

It's certainly not an urgent issue and it isn't anything that impedes the site's use, but I believe that if the Super User iPhone Home Screen Icon had a white background it would be more iconic and certainly more pleasing to the eye.

[image: Retina iPhone Icons]

---

Note that nearly a year later, after Arqade (Gaming) and Role-Playing got new icons, the Super User icon is still the same.

---

[image: Retina iPhone Icons]

Comment: That iPhone must be huge

Comment: How about switching the dark gray to a white for the left half of the logo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also started bookmarking SE sites on my home screen and noticed the Super User logo looked out of place. However, I don't think a white background should be added, as that would remove the consistency with all the other icons. I like M. Tibbit's suggestion (in fact, I thought the same thing) of making the left half of the face white instead. Here is a quick mockup I made (doesn't it look fantastic):

[image: "A masterpiece! Look at the way he used the brush tool!"]

Comment: Very much agreed. I had the same thoughts when I read the question. Keeping the black theme for consistency with the other icons and the default home screen is a good idea. The logo is still instantly recognizable in white.

Comment: I like this idea too.

Comment: This also matches with the color scheme for the SU t-shirt on black, so I'm sure they already have the design files for it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is not with Super User putting a black background behind the icon.  The icon itself has a transparent background.  By default, Apple places a black background behind icons that are transparent.  On the Android, the icon itself floats on the home screen, without the background (and both devices use the same file for the icon).

Now, I wouldn't have an issue with using the icon with a lighter gray color, but the black background you see isn't anything that Stack Exchange did, it's a ('nuther) peculiarity of Apple.